# Move from multiple repositories to a monorepo (on GitLab)

Tags: git, gitlab

I have created an application with a front and back end, I have pushed every service in a different git repository hosted on GitLab. Now I want to merge these two repositories in a single repository to have a monorepo and make my pipelines, while every service would be in a different directory without losing any branches or changes. I tried to fetch and change the remote but it was a mess, and I would like a more clean work. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Have you heard of `git submodule` or `git subtree`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will stay a mess if you merge separate pieces of software with separate histories in one repository. That is not how versioning should be used.

For projects that are to be separately version controlled but still used by a single piece of software in one repository, there should be one repository each compontent. This will allow you to fine tune the deploy procedures individually in a manageable and documentable way and, even more important, keep the history clean. Imagine in the future you would be looking for one specific version of one specific component. It would be lost in the history of your project, that, after all, is not even the history of said subcomponent.

There is a solution though if you need the projects interconnected and under common version control: *submodules*. Check out the official documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). It will allow you to keep track of individual histories and share resources at the same time. Integration in your pipeline will be seamlessly possible. Also it will give you distinct control over the versions of each project being in the shared space.

So my solution to your problem: Refactor. Separate the projects to individual repositories, each with its own deployment strategy working just fine. Then, to interconnect them and share resources, make them submodules of the project you want them to work in side by side with other software: create a new repository and add them in as submodules.

Comment: I think I will take the master branch of each repository then orgnise my project proprely, it would be the best solution I think.

Comment: By "organizing" you mean statically copying the state of the master branch to your project? Be aware that by doing so you lose the option on version history for all your subprojects. Actually this is exactly what submodules are made for; retaining individual history in a nested repo. Think about it.